# How to estimate amount of disk space required for gdal.Translate?

Tags: gdal, gdal-translate, mosaic, gdalbuildvrt

I've got a raster dataset (>10000 tiles) I want to merge into one single file (mosaic). For this purpose, I'm using a 2-step algo:

1. create a **.VRT** file with `gdal.BuildVRT` (no options)
2. create a **.TIFF** mosaic out of the provided **.VRT** file with `gdal.Translate` (with creation options `['BIGTIFF=YES', 'TILED=YES']`)

At certain point, I get this error:

```
ERROR 3: Free disk space available is N bytes, whereas M are at least necessary.
```

It occurs when I have 128GB of free disk space, but when I increase it up to 256GB - the algo succeeds.

So my question is: is there a way to estimate the amount of disk space required for such algo beforehand? Say, `source_dataset_size * ? = disk_space_required`

**NOTE**: I need to estimate disk space required temporarily while `gdal.Translate` is executing. It seems that if I have a 30GB dataset, GDAL can take up much more (triple the size of the dataset?) disc space before saving the resulting file.

My setup:

- Dockerized Debian 12 (bookworm)
- GDAL 3.6.2
- Python 3.11.6

Info about dataset:

- 10000 .geotiff tiles 3.1MB each
- Tile resolution: 1024x1024
- Bands: RGB
- Data type: UInt8
- Compression: No data
- CRS: 4326

**UPDATE #1**
I got the preliminary calculations wrong. Based on formula provided by @user30184, I got an estimated size of 33GB. Unfortunately, this doesn't answer my question.

The resulting file size is 33.5GB. It's `66560 x 167936` pixels.

**UPDATE #2**
Accepted @user30184's answer as it gives correct guidance and suggestions regarding how to calculate disc space needed for a generic case. My case requires much more thorough testing and does seem to be rather a corner case.

Comment: The uncompressed size is simply the total count of pixels * bytes per pixel * number of bands. An example: 10000 x 10000 pixel sized 8-bit RGB image takes `10000*10000*1*3=300 MB`.

Comment: That is a perfect answer, @user30184, why not post it? :)

Comment: Please tell how to repeat your test with a 30 GB dataset.

Comment: @user30184, unfortunately, I cannot provide the files since they represent confidential info.

Comment: I do not need your files. I can create some 30 GB dataset for testing myself. Provide general info about what kind of files you have, what commands did you use, and perhaps some info about your environment like operating system and file system.

Comment: @user30184, I updated the original post with the requested info. Also, I noticed an error in my previous calculations which means the formula you provided didn't help to answer the question. I had to unmark you answer as a solution. Apologies for that.

Comment: What is the size of the originals in pixels? What is the size of the output in pixels? What is the size of the resulting TIFF in gigabytes file when the process succeeds?

Comment: @user30184, I updated original post with the info. I cannot grasp what the issue is all about. Your formula is correct and does correspond to the result. But why GDAL raises the error... Is it because of Docker or, perhaps, specific GDAL version?

Comment: It is not uncommon to have a VRT with more than 10000 source files but certainly your use case is not the most thoroughly tested. It may be that using so big virtual raster exceeds some limits and triggers the need to use temporary files or something Testing would require about similar set-up that you have and feels like is would take much more free time than I can use. Maybe adding `--debug on` into the command gives information about what is going on when the error message appears.  I would test with a small vrt and add more source files into it for seeing if the need of space grows linearly

Comment: @user30184, good point. Thank you for all the suggestions. I will proceed with a thorough testing to finally find the culprit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The uncompressed size is simply the total count of pixels * bytes per pixel * number of bands. An example: 10000 x 10000 pixel sized 8-bit RGB image takes `10000*10000*1*3=300 MB`.

Compressed size is harder to estimate because the nature of the source data and compression options can have a huge effect on the final size. I suggest compressing a small sample with your own data and desired compression settings first. As a rule of thumb for satellite images lossless compression with LZW or deflate methods saves 20-30% and lossy JPEG compression with 80 % quality settings saves 80-90% of disk space. Numbers are about the final size. During processing programs like gdal_translate and gdalwarp may need more disk space.

Some GDAL drivers and programs need to use temporary files. In that case there must be enough space also on the drive where the temporary files are written. See for example https://gdal.org/drivers/raster/pdf.html#podofo.

> A temporary file will be generated in a directory determined by the
> following configuration options : CPL_TMPDIR, TMPDIR or TEMP (in that
> order). If none are defined, the current directory will be used.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. The problem is that I need to estimate disk space that is temporarily required during executing gdal.Translate. I don't need to estimate the size of the resulting mosaic.

Comment: As far as I know gdal_translate does not use temporary files and the size of the resulting mosaic is exactly what you need to know. Run gdalinfo for your .vrt file and for seeing the width and height, band count, and bit depth of the mosaic.

Comment: Compression makes files smaller. Maybe you have compressed source files. And if the files in the vrt are not adjacent the empty space between the source images contains empty pixels but they require as much space as any other pixel when there is no compression.

Comment: I didn't apply compression. gdal.Info didn't find one in the original data.